# Use of unresolved identifier iOS Swift 3.0 GVR SDK

Tags: ios, swift, identifier

I'm trying to read video in a stereo mode using GVR SDK for iOS (In Swift).

For that, I'm calling my videos via:

```
videoVRView.load(from: URL(string: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"))
```

Which call video to be play in Mono - that works perfectly.

Otherwise the reference mention that the loadfromurl is only for mono video:

https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/reference/interface_g_v_r_video_view#ac849aa112138433a2be90f6910c84918

and I should use loadfromurl oftype to play video in stereo

https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/reference/g_v_r_video_view_8h#a7cb3bbc06fa053a4d1ade6014a3ac6ec

So I have change my code to:

```
videoVRView.load(from: URL(string: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"), ofType: kGVRVideoTypeStereoOverUnder)
```

but I'm getting this error now:

> 'Use of unresolved identifier kGVRVideoTypeStereoOverUnder'

Anybody would know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried GVRVideoType.kGVRVideoTypeStereoOverUnder instead?

Comment: I see that the page you linked mentions a file called GVRVideoView.h.  How are you connecting the SDK to your project?  Is there a bridging header that needs to include that file?

Comment: I got at the end via, thx guys !      videoVRView.load(from: URL(string: "\(posts[selectedIndexPath].link)"), of: GVRVideoType.stereoOverUnder

Comment: problem is now, He doesnt call the Mono video correctly -__-